# how to change an object array into a simple object

Tags: javascript

I have the following table :

```
     [
      {
         "fr": {
           "strenghts": [
            {
            "icon": "fa-briefcase",
            "title": "Marketing"
            }             
        ]
      }
     },
     {
      en: {
        strenghts: [
          {
            icon: 'fa-briefcase',
            title: 'Marketing'                 
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 ]
```

and I would like to transform it into a simple object like this :

```
var test = {
      "fr": {
        "strenghts": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-briefcase",
            "title": "Marketing"
          }             
        ]
      }
     },
     {
      "en": {
        "strenghts": [
          {
            "icon": "fa-briefcase",
            "title": "Marketing"                
           }              
        ]
      }
    }
```

if you have a solution that could help me ? to transform my object array into a simple object

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: That isn't "a simple object". That's two objects separated by a comma which would be a syntax error.

Comment: @RoToRa it is possible to reformat the starting json

Comment: @Greg-A I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following code, you can get the expected output.

```
let array = [
{
   "fr": {
     "strenghts": [{
        "icon": "fa-briefcase",
        "title": "Marketing"
      }]
    }
},
{
   en: {
    strenghts: [{
        icon: 'fa-briefcase',
        title: 'Marketing'                 
     }]
    }
  }
]

const arrayToObject = (array) =>
   array.reduce((obj, item) => {
      let key = Object.keys(item);
      obj[key[0]] = item[key[0]];
      return obj
}, {})

const object = arrayToObject(array)
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list = [{
    "fr": {
      "strenghts": [{
        "icon": "fa-briefcase",
        "title": "Marketing"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    en: {
      strenghts: [{
        icon: 'fa-briefcase',
        title: 'Marketing'
      }]
    }
  }
]

var test = list.reduce(function(acc, x) {
  for (var key in x) acc[key] = x[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(test);
```

You eventually want to merge all the objects in the array you listed in to one object. You can follow the below link to see a solution on stack overflow

See [MDN docs for reduce for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused with `reduce` semantic and functional programming you could use this alternative solution. Note that this only works in your format namely if the object nested into array has more than one key it doesn't work

```js
var list = [{
    "fr": {
      "strenghts": [{
        "icon": "fa-briefcase",
        "title": "Marketing"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    en: {
      strenghts: [{
        icon: 'fa-briefcase',
        title: 'Marketing'
      }]
    }
  }
]

var test = {};
for(let obj of list)
{
   let key = Object.keys(obj);
   test[key] = obj[key];
}

console.log(test);
```